# Could someone please explain how integers in the form of 0x0 etc work?

Tags: memory, ram

As the title says, could someone please explain how integers work, like those seen in memory addresses. Any answers would be greatly appreciated; the context of the situation is that I want to be able to view edit and delete data stored in a processes allocated memory.

Thanks :D

Comment: More specifically, RAM pointers (sorry I don't have enough knowledge to really ask this question do I haha)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

0x00 notation means that the number is in Hexadecimal Format. Mostly these numbers are used for the memory location addresses or the read/write data packet formats. This  [link](http://www.linfo.org/hexadecimal.html) might help.

Comment: Thanks :D At least someone understands me :D

Comment: Welcome. Actually a few weeks ago, I was struggling with the same thing. :P